how to find script in pipeline project
I created a Jenkins pipeline task and used Git to maintain Jenkinsfile. The directory structure of the project is:

maven


shell






deploy.sh






Jenkinsfile


node


shell






deploy.sh






Jenkinsfile



Jenkinsfile:
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Clone Code') {
            steps {                
                script {
                    def branch_info = "${Branch}".split("/")
                    
                    cloneBranch = branch_info[-1]
                    imageTag = "${harbor}/${type}/${Project_name}:${cloneBranch}"
                }
                echo "clone ${Project_name} code branch: ${cloneBranch}, url: ${codeRepo}"

                git branch: cloneBranch, credentialsId: authId, url: codeRepo
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                // 部署到目标服务器
                echo "deploy: ${server}"
                
                script {
                    withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: serverAuth, keyFileVariable: 'identity', usernameVariable: 'username')]) {
                        def remote = [:]
                        remote.name = 'backend'
                        remote.host = server
                        remote.port = 22
                        remote.allowAnyHosts = true
                        remote.user = username
                        remote.identityFile = identity

                        // 删除旧脚本文件
                        sshCommand remote: remote, command: 'rm -f /tmp/deploy.sh'

                        // 上传脚本文件
                        sshPut remote: remote, from: 'shell/deploy.sh', into: '/tmp/'

                        // 运行部署服务脚本文件
                        sshCommand remote: remote, command: 'bash /tmp/deploy.sh ${Project_name} ${imageTag}'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The target project for pipeline execution and construction is another project, such as the springboot project. That is to say, the link for Pipeline script from SCM is not the same as the link in the Close Repo stage
At a certain stage, send the shell/deploy.sh file to the target server and execute the script file.
Execution result error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/web-pipeline/shell/deploy.sh does not exist.
how to find target file: shell/deploy.sh?
I have no idea
。

The default checkout runs your pipeline in the root folder of your repo, not in the folder where your Jenkinsfile is, so the path would be either 'maven/shell/deploy.sh' or 'node/shell/deploy.sh'

get error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/web-pipeline/maven/shell/deploy.sh does not exist.   The pipeline project and the construction target project are separate, Jenkinsfile was in pipeline project

What do you mean by "project"? Repository? Your question only mentions "the project", please update it to explain what other projects you have and why it might be relevant.

Sorry, I didn't make myself clear, I have re edited the question and added a description of the problem
